# window.onerror in Safari ( Javascript )

Tags: javascript, error-handling

I create an error message its working with IE and Mozila.
Not woking with Safari, Chrome and Opera.

But I need to use it. Please give me right way for doing it.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
window.onerror = function(msg, url, line)
{
    document.write("Message\t = "+msg + "<br/>Location\t = " + url + "<br/>Line No.\t = " + line + "<br/>Error No.\t = " + this.err.number);
}
this.err = Error(12,"My Own Error");
throw this.err;
</script>

==========================================
Internet Explorer:

My Error
Message = My Own Error
Location = http://localhost/practice/JavaScript/window.errors.php
Line No. = 8
Error No. = 12 
================================================
Mozilla FireFox:

My Error
Message = Script error.
Location = My Own Error
Line No. = 0
Error No. = undefined 
=====================================================
Safari, Chrome, Opera:

My Error
```

look the code Mozilla give wrong information. what I do?

Comment: *(Reference)* http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/error.html the event is indeed very badly supported on IE and FF; not sure whether there is anything that can be done about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Opera doesn't support `window.onerror` at all.  Chrome supports it, but not on errors that you throw yourself.  This is also true of Internet Explorer when using Error objects other than `Error()`, e.g. `TypeError()`.  Chrome also doesn't provide the *line* and *file* arguments.

You should correctly catch any exceptions you're going to throw with a `try...catch` statement, instead of relying on `window.onerror`.

Comment: The point is to catch exceptions/errors you are NOT going to throw, but which are likely to happen in a sufficiently complex JS (for example, to show a nice apology message to the user). I'm looking at the same problem myself, and Chrome/Safari don't catch invalid reference errors - which are arguably the most frequent.

Comment: @sereda: then I'm afraid you're out of luck, unless you want to wrap each block of code with try and catch statements (please don't :-)).  The solution, of course, is to write error free code and test as much as humanly possible.

Comment: @AndyE You can only write as bug free code as your 3rd party libraries let you.  For example, I ended up here because I have to use the buggy Facebook Javascript library, and the exception they are throwing isn't even catchable via try/catch because it triggers from a dialog they control.

Comment: ' The solution, of course, is to write error free code and test as much as humanly possible.'.  - The solution is not grounded in reality.